# After delete Azure Active directory user and resync. I lost access to multyple places in AzureDevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

After delete Azure Active directory user and resync. I lost access to multyple places, company environment in AzureDevOps

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was in the role of administrator and was a member of all the necessary security groups. The problem is most likely due to the fact that after deleting the Directory from Azure Active and a new full synchronization, I probably received a new SID. Проблема так и не решена (FacePalm)

Comment: No my issue is not solved

Comment: Could you describe what exactly changed after you resync?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you can not access some resources in Azure DevOps, you need to check the access level and permission of your account and the group you belong to.

First, check the access level of your account or group. If you have Stakeholder access level, change to Basic level:

> The **Basic** access level and higher supports full access to all
> Azure Boards features. **Stakeholder** access level provides partial
> support to select features, allowing users to view and modify work
> items, but not use all features. **Stakeholder** access is available
> to support free access to a limited set of features by an unlimited
> set of stakeholders.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions-access?view=azure-devops

If the access level is already Basic level, check the permission of your account or group. You need to check the following link to grant your account or group appropriate permission for the resources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page